# Cloudflare ReCaptcha Challange Bypass with Python

Tags: python, python-requests, recaptcha, captcha, cloudflare

I want to bypass a Cloudflare ReCaptcha Challange at the beginning of a Website to scrape it with Python.

I have an API that is solving the ReCaptcha. If I add the "g-recaptcha-response" from the API
directly via Inspect Elements from Chrome and press the Button to submit it will work 100% and bypasses the captcha.

**Screenshot to understand what I mean:**

[image]

BUT, my problem now is that if I make a GET request to the Request URL bellow with all the Parameters with python requests to that form with the token and all the hidden input fields
it just won't work and don't bypass it. It doesn't return me the cookie name "cf_clearance".

**Here is a successfully GET Request Bypass through the Browser:**

```
Request URL: https://example.com/cdn-cgi/l/chk_captcha?s=ce4cb15ca466e2813fd8ac9ca2b53447526e3353-1558445818-1800-Adz12DeT4OTVwi5Kk0Wvjf4vFnoZhT0Sl6WGNhwCcQAf8opJzWm%2B74Y%2BtmE1GoNSrsuN0xZnohsi%2B5touRT5j2VkVW8oIgmCsCmU95BANSslZ%2FVrn7RtTCrPc1PAIYKuxjWjcv0CVnlwFLt0K5ug6ao%3D&id=4da6f13e8c73bf37&g-recaptcha-response=03AOLTBLQAPYFRmnMBUGaS2YQ1z5M9Jd-g1x7bDZ9kqHiEbzLXw9eIzCetSnpe3H29gBW0glMMPfQ9bAX4Fa5gTCEwazwoL_6K5iXJPclXV1KYme6BIJEkx3LzP0yUGHjxwTTHtv6rodMOO63tVefrMbOIltI36I1HSjfYfQRSFSNRWnIJp0_NYhtm-_juQv7ONUqtE-tHvy_8mKgm93tJ2itRKu9zSgCe88tLF44RD4o_Vcf18dFjUAifhlf520gTO5zGP4QakaZZn_cbJYW1okLvbKYUmO7qJSWo_dApWa1hKlNI1ePOclZ-uxi3kdkh0yXz1Slv85eK&bf_challenge_id=6980&bf_execution_time=59&bf_result_hash=1690145601

Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
cf-ray: 4da6f180be12bf37-AMS
content-length: 159
content-type: text/html
date: Tue, 21 May 2019 13:37:09 GMT
location: /
server: cloudflare
set-cookie: cf_clearance=e498c598ebd08715124534543d7035c2348bc06-1558445829-1800-250; path=/; expires=Tue, 21-May-19 15:07:09 GMT; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly
status: 302
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
:authority: example.com
:method: GET
:path: /cdn-cgi/l/chk_captcha?s=ce4cb15ca466e2813fd8ac9ca2b53447526e3353-1558445818-1800-Adz12DeT4OTVwi5Kk0Wvjf4vFnoZhT0Sl6WGNhwCcQAf8opJzWm%2B74Y%2BtmE1GoNSrsuN0xZnohsi%2B5touRT5j2VkVW8oIgmCsCmU95BANSslZ%2FVrn7RtTCrPc1PAIYKuxjWjcv0CVnlwFLt0K5ug6ao%3D&id=4da6f13e8c73bf37&g-recaptcha-response=03AOLTBLQAPYFRmnMBUGaS2YQ1z5M9Jd-g1x7bDZ9kqHiEbzLXw9eIzCetSnpe3H29gBW0glMMPfQ9bAX4Fa5gTCEwazwoL_6K5iXJPclXV1KYme6BIJEkx3LzP0yUGHjxwTTHtv6rodMOO63tVefrMbOIltI36I1HSjfYfQRSFSNRWnIJp0_NYhtm-_juQv7ONUqtE-tHvy_8mKgm93tJ2itRKu9zSgCe88tLF44RD4o_Vcf18dFjUAifhlf520gTO5zGP4QakaZZn_cbJYW1okLvbKYUmO7qJSWo_dApWa1hKlNI1ePOclZ-uxi3kdkh0yXz1Slv85eK&bf_challenge_id=6980&bf_execution_time=59&bf_result_hash=1690145601
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cookie: __cfduid=ddf2d99d0f94543554e8b284e91556383068
referer: https://example.com
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36
s: ce4cb15ca466e2813fd8ac9ca2b53447526e3353-1558445818-1800-Adz12DeT4OTVwi5Kk0Wvjf4vFnoZhT0Sl6WGNhwCcQAf8opJzWm+74Y+tmE1GoNSrsuN0xZnohsi+5touRT5j2VkVW8oIgmCsCmU95BANSslZ/Vrn7RtTCrPc1PAIYKuxjWjcv0CVnlwFLt0K5ug6ao=
id: 4da6f13e8c73bf37
g-recaptcha-response: 03AOLTBLQAPYFRmnMBUGaS2YQ1z5M9Jd-g1x7bDZ9kqHiEbzLXw9eIzCetSnpe3H29gBW0glMMPfQ9bAX4Fa5gTCEwazwoL_6K5iXJPclXV1KYme6BIJEkx3LzP0yUGHjxwTTHtv6rodMOO63tVefrMbOIltI36I1HSjfYfQRSFSNRWnIJp0_NYhtm-_juQv7ONUqtE-tHvy_8mKgm93tJ2itRKu9zSgCe88tLF44RD4o_Vcf18dFjUAifhlf520gTO5zGP4QakaZZn_cbJYW1okLvbKYUmO7qJSWo_dApWa1hKlNI1ePOclZ-uxi3kdkh0yXz1Slv85eK
bf_challenge_id: 6980
bf_execution_time: 59
bf_result_hash: 1690145601
```

Am I missing something or why does Cloudflare does not accept it? And how I would make it accept it with a python request.